# Laravel Routing to Views in Subdirectories

Tags: laravel, routes, view, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel, and have a view structure like such:

[image]

Each of my pages have a navbar at the top, and the navbar has a few links on it:

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
 <li><a href="mykennel/info">KENNEL INFORMATION</a></li>
 <li><a href="mykennel/parents">SIRES & DAMS</a></li>
 <li><a href="mykennel/litters">LITTERS</a></li>
 <li><a href="help/breeder">HELP</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I click one of these links (lets say info) from the homepage (home.blade.php), it redirects to the following url:

> localhost:8080/mykennel/info

However, if I'm already on a view that is in the mykennel subfolder (again, lets say I'm on the info page), and I click a link from the navbar, it redirects to:

> localhost:8080/mykennel/**mykennel**/info

Which throws a 404. I understand WHY this is happening but I can't seem to find how to fix it. How can I create an href in my anchor tag that knows to use only a single /mykennel/ prefix, regardless of where the user is currently situated on the site?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add `/` at the beginning of your `href` so links become `/mykennel/*`

Comment: LOL. Thank you, that fixed it. Happy to mark your answer if you make one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an absolute path instead, by adding `/` at the beginning of the `href` so links:

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav">
  <li><a href="/mykennel/info">KENNEL INFORMATION</a></li>
  <li><a href="/mykennel/parents">SIRES & DAMS</a></li>
  <li><a href="/mykennel/litters">LITTERS</a></li>
  <li><a href="/help/breeder">HELP</a></li>
</ul>
```